# Magento 2.4 libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile, Wrong file, file does not exist

Tags: magento2.4, product-images, image-resize, png

I'm getting this error "**libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile**"
when running **php bin/magento catalog:image:resize**.
Please is there anyone who could help me get this fixed? Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: This is not Magento related. This is because you have an PNG image with invalid iCCP chunk. You have to remove image or remove iCCP chunk from the PNG image. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile

Answer (score 0):

> When checking images ICC profiles, Magento 2 did not find iCCP chunk in PNG image profile, thus the system automatically throws this error message and stop the image resize process

For More:  http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html

Connect to your server using SSH as the root user and use the following syntax to remove iCCP chunks from PNG Images on your website.

If your image files are located in **pub/media**

```
find pub/media -type f -iname '*.png' -exec pngcrush -ow -rem allb -reduce {} \;
```

Next, re-run the image resize command and the issue is fixed, you now can resize images normally

If you see the error: Wrong file. That means the files you want to resize do not exist in the folder. Recheck the image files in that folder or you can force Magento 2 to ingore this error and continue the process by editing **vendor/magento/module-media-storage/Service/ImageResize.php** file and put the update if condition. find

```
if ($this->mediaDirectory->isFile($originalImagePath)) -> if ($this->mediaDirectory->isFile($originalImagePath) && filesize({path_to_the_file}))
```

Now all the error should go away and you can process image resize normally

Answer (score 0):

solution example you can implement to amend/remove the wrong profile on the fly

- Pick any solution which can support calling external util, eg `pgncrush` - I decided to roll composer package ***[flynsarmy/image-optimizer](https://github.com/Flynsarmy/image-optimizer)*** (based on ***[ps/image-optimizer](https://github.com/psliwa/image-optimizer)*** but with php8+ support - thanks for the creators)
- ensure the chosen util is installed to the server
- try-catch the error
- Initiate and run optimizer as follows

```
            $optimizerFactory = new \ImageOptimizer\OptimizerFactory(
                    [
                        'custom_optimizers' => [
                            'pngcrush_iccp_removal' => [
                                'command' => 'pngcrush',
                                'args' => ['-ow',  '-rem',  'allb', '-reduce'],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                );
                try {
                    $optimizerFactory->get('pngcrush_iccp_removal')->optimize($this->_fileName);
                    $this->_imageHandler = call_user_func(
                        $this->_getCallback('create', null, sprintf('Unsupported image format. File: %s', $this->_fileName)),
                        $this->_fileName
                    );
                } catch (\ImageOptimizer\Exception\CommandNotFound $e) {
                    $this->logger->notice('Optimizer `pngcrush` not available');
                } catch (\ImageOptimizer\Exception\Exception $e) {
                    $this->logger->notice('Optimizer `pngcrush` failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
                }
```

as called method *$this->_callback* and property *$this->_fileName*, it can be seen that the modifications are over the core Gd2 image adapter (Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2)

The changes can be pushed as a composer patch or the file can be overridden/preferenced - you can even use a before plugin in Gd2:open() to optimize any image tried to be opened by the adapter

In addition, you can choose any external utils, like `morgify` - also freely can change the argument list as well opposed to my solution. You can find several different utils and argument lists : [stackoverflow/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile) is a hot topic of the same issue